# How to set share permissions based on folder structure

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs, network-shares

The problem I'm having is that users are moving folders around in a tree-like folder organization on the shared drive. User education has not improved the issue so i want to use permissions to restrict what folders can be moved and where. I want to leave the first 2 tiers of folders but restrict tiers 3 & 4 to read only permissions  and give modify permissions from tier 5 to infinity without having to touch all existing folders.

`\\server\share\[%year]\[%project name]\[%content folder]\content.doc`

`\\modify\modify\ read \    read       \      modify     \  modify`

My prayer is that someone can show me how to set permissions for a folder based on its Depth in the folder structure (understanding that if another layer of parent folder is introduced, it would alter the permissions of the children based on their new tier in the tree).

Is this a realistic concept or am i about to spend a week restructuring permissions piecemeal?

Answer (score 0):

> **How to set share permissions based on folder structure**
>
> The problem I'm having is that users are moving folders around in a
>   tree-like folder organization on the shared drive.

I've tackled this problem in the past in a Windows Domain Environment with [**ICACLS**](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) using the below commands to lock down the folders to ensure those cannot be moved (or deleted) by the user account or the user accounts in the security group which has MODIFY access to the folder (see below ICACLS Command Prompt Example syntax, etc.).

You can replace **SecurityGroupName** with **Username** if that's how you're securing your network share folder resource.

### ICACLS Command Prompt Example

```
ICACLS "\\Server\Share\Folder\<Folder Name To Lock Down>" /deny "SecurityGroupName":(DE)
```

### Options Used

> **/deny user:permission** - Explicitly deny the specified user access
>   rights.    This will also remove any explicit grant of the     same
>   permissions to the same user.
>
> **(DE)** - Deny delete permission explicitly at the top level folder only which also prevents accidental drag and drop. The file-level archive attribute is checked on all files within a folder you make this change to so this may have an effect on your file-level backup jobs.

---

> someone can show me how to set permissions for a folder based on its
>   Depth in the folder structure

As far as your structure is concerned though, grant the users\security groups read-access at the top-level, and then where they need MODIFY access, grant that explicitly at those subfolder levels there. I'm going to assume you're familiar with the actual options to set these permissions at the folder levels where it's needed and just needed advice on where to set these permissions at more than anything.

Try to keep folder level security as standard as possible, and if you need to set permissions explicitly more than 3 or 4 level down (at least in the business types I support) then that MAY imply a bad design.

Typically we try to keep it two layers only such as `/department/subdepartment` (e.g. `/Finance/Accounts Payable`, `/Finance/Payroll`, and so on).  The managers or executives would get MODIFY from the top level all the way down, then the subdeparments would only get access to the subdepartments they belong to.

As far as the `\\server\share` part of the UNC path, I typically grant READ access here at these levels and then groups that need more will get what they need at the `~\department\~` or `~\department\subdepartment` levels as I listed in the above paragraph. The main point is to NOT allow someone access to a department or some folder they are not supposed to have access to.